# edit footer FooTable

Tags: jquery, css, html, footable

I use  [FooTable](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/index.html)  plugin

After init I try

```
  'on': {
  'postinit.ft.table': function(e, ft) {
    var
      rows = table.rows.array;
    for (var i = 0, l = rows.length, row; i < l; i++) {
      row = rows[i].val();
      total_sum += parseInt(row["sum_product"]);
      total_count += parseInt(row["count_product"]);
    }
    var foot = $("#purchases_table").find('tfoot');

    foot.prepend(
      "<tr><th rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"1\">SUMM</th><th  rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"3\"></th><th id='count_product_all' rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"1\">" + total_count + "</th><th id='sum_product_all' rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"1\">" + total_sum + "</th><th rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"4\"></th></tr>\n");
  },
```

And all ok
and I need change this dynamic

```
'draw.ft.table': function(e, ft) {
  var rows = ft.rows.all;
  total_sum = 0;
  total_count = 0;
  for (var i = 0, l = rows.length, row; i < l; i++) {
    row = rows[i].val();
    total_sum += parseInt(row["sum_product"]);
    total_count += parseInt(row["count_product"]);
  }
  $("#count_product_all").html(total_count);
  $("#sum_product_all").html(total_sum);
}
},
```

But in html `count_product_all` and `sum_product_all` changed only for 1 second and go back to 0 why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can u check if only enter one time at  $("#count_product_all").html(total_count); please.

like this:

```
'draw.ft.table': function(e, ft) {
 var rows = ft.rows.all;
 bool enter = false;
 total_sum = 0;
 total_count = 0;
 for (var i = 0, l = rows.length, row; i < l; i++) {
  row = rows[i].val();
total_sum += parseInt(row["sum_product"]);
total_count += parseInt(row["count_product"]);

enter = true;
 }
 if(enter){
$("#count_product_all").html(total_count);
 $("#sum_product_all").html(total_sum);

  enter = false;
}

}
},
```